# Managed DigitalOcean Redis instance giving Redis AbortError

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, sails.js, digital-ocean

I setup managed redis and managed postgres on digital ocean. Digital ocean gave me a `.crt` file, I don't know what to do with this, so didn't do anything with it. Can this be the root of the problem below:

Or do I have to allow docker container to reach outside of the container on the `rediss` protocol?

I dockerized a node app and then put this container onto my droplet. I have my droplet and managed redis and postgres in same region (SFO2). It connects to redis using this url:

```
url: 'rediss://default:REMOVED_THIS_PASSWORD@my-new-app-sfo2-do-user-5053627-0.db.ondigitalocean.com:25061/0',
```

I then did ran my docker container with `docker run`.

It then gives me error:

```
node_redis: WARNING: You passed "rediss" as protocol instead of the "redis" protocol!

events.js:186
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
AbortError: Connection forcefully ended and command aborted. It might have been processed.
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/index.js:362:23)
    at RedisClient.end (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/lib/extendedApi.js:52:14)
    at RedisClient.onPreConnectionEnd (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/machinepack-redis/machines/get-connection.js:157:14)
    at RedisClient.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at RedisClient.connection_gone (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/index.js:590:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/index.js:293:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:298:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:214:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1178:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at /opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/index.js:310:22
    at Object.callbackOrEmit [as callback_or_emit] (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/lib/utils.js:89:9)
    at Command.callback (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/lib/individualCommands.js:199:15)
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/index.js:374:29)
    at RedisClient.end (/opt/apps/mynewapp/node_modules/redis/lib/extendedApi.js:52:14)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'NR_CLOSED',
  command: 'AUTH',
  args: [ 'REMOVED_I_DONT_KNOW_IF_THIS_IS_SENSITIVE' ]
```

Comment: its rediss or Redis??

Comment: @Subburaj digital ocean says it is `rediss` (2 s's)

Answer (score 2):

The `redis` protocol is different from `rediss` because the latter uses TLS connection. DigitalOcean Managed Redis [requires the connections to be made over TLS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/cheatsheets/how-to-connect-to-a-redis-database#connecting-to-redis), so you have to use `rediss`. However, I couldn't find any info about the TLS certificate provided by DigitalOcean to connect to the Managed Redis service.

Based on your error message, I presumed you're using [this redis package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis). If that's the case, you can pass empty TLS object option in the connection string like so:

```js
const Redis = require('redis')

const host = 'db-redis.db.ondigitalocean.com'
const port = '25061'
const username = 'user'
const password = 'secret'
const url = `${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}`

const client = Redis.createClient(url, {tls: {}})
```

Further reading/source:

1. [SSL connections arrive for Redis on Compose](https://www.compose.com/articles/ssl-connections-arrive-for-redis-on-compose/)
2. [Connecting to IBM Cloud Databases for Redis from Node.js](http://jamesthom.as/2019/07/connecting-to-ibm-cloud-databases-for-redis-from-node.js/)

Comment: Thanks razu for your message, you are right you have to pass in that `tls: {}` I actually solved it but forgot to share my answer. I'll sharei t below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Below are snippets from `config/env/production.js`

#### Sockets

For sockets, to enable `rediss` you have to pass in all options through `adapterOptions` like this:

```
sockets: {
  onlyAllowOrigins: ['https://my-website.com'],

  // pass in as adapterOptions so it gets through to redis-adapter
  // as i need it "rediss" but this url is not supported i get an error.
  // so i need to pass in `tls` empty object. and i see he moves things into
  // `adapterOptions` here here - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-sockets/blob/master/lib/configure.js#L128
  adapterOptions: {
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password',
    host: 'host',
    port: 9999,
    db: 2, // pick a number
    tls: {},
  },

  adapter: '@sailshq/socket.io-redis',
},
```

#### Session

For session, pass `tls: {}` empty object to config:

```
session: {
  pass: 'password',
  host: 'host',
  port: 9999,
  db: 1, // pick a number not used by sockets
  tls: {},
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
  },
},
```